# How to get object at CreatView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

There is a form that is rendered by url

```
url(r'kredit/(?P<credit_slug>[-\.\w\d]+)/$', CreditDetail.as_view(), name='credit_detail'),
```

## urls

```
url(r'kredit/(?P<credit_slug>[-\.\w\d]+)/$', CreditDetail.as_view(), name='credit_detail'),
url(r'kredit_request/$', CreditOnlineRequestView.as_view(), name='credit_request'),
```

The form is processed in the `CreditOnlineRequestView(CreateView)` view.
It is necessary to pull out the credit_slug from `CreditDetail` view in it (here the form was drawn)
​

## views

```
class CreditDetail(FormView):
    form_class = CreditPaymentForm
    template_name = 'credits/credit_detail.html'
​
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CreditDetail, self).get_initial()
        initial['request'] = self.request
        return initial
​
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request_form = CreditOnlineRequestForm(self.request.GET or None, prefix="request")
​
​
class CreditOnlineRequestView(CreateView):
    form_class = CreditOnlineRequestForm
    model = CreditOnlineRequest
    template_name = 'credits/credit_listing.html'
    prefix = 'request'
​
    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        credit_request = form.save(commit=False)
        credit_request.credit = credit                     #???
        return super(CreditOnlineRequestView, self).form_valid(form)
​
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        errors = dict([(k, v[0]) for k, v in form.errors.items()])
        return errors
```

## forms

```
class CreditOnlineRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreditOnlineRequest
        exclude = ['credit']           #this field must be define
​
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreditOnlineRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #???
```

What are the options? I think, either through the `cache`, or through pulling out the `previous page` to do, but this is somehow not very humane, as for me. The best option, as for me, is to transfer the credit instance to a `hidden form field` in the `CreditDetail` view, but I don’t know how to do it yet.

Comment: Can you explain better which object do you want to get and where? Thanks.

Comment: The `CreditOnlineRequest model` is associated with the `Credit model` by the `credit field` through `FK`. In the form I do not need to display this field, so I `excluded` it. And now when I try to create a `CreditOnlineRequest` object, I get an error saying that the `credit == null` field. Everything is logical. But how can I define this field? ..

Comment: Okey understood! Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**urls**

```
url(r'kredit_request/(?P<credit_slug>[-\.\w\d]+)/$', CreditOnlineRequestView.as_view(), name='credit_request'),
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'credit_request' credit.slug %}" method="post">
```

**view**

```
class CreditOnlineRequestView(CreateView):
    form_class = CreditOnlineRequestForm
    model = CreditOnlineRequest
    slug_url_kwarg = 'credit_slug'
    prefix = 'request'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        credit = Credit.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('credit_slug'))
        cache.set('credit_for_request', credit)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        credit_request = form.save(commit=False)
        credit = cache.get('credit_for_request')
        cache.clear()
        credit_request.credit = credit
        credit_request.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('credit_detail', kwargs={'credit_slug': credit.slug}))
```

Comment: You can acces kwargs from `form_valid` using `self.request.kwargs`.

Comment: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that internally the `form_valid` function is doing the following:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

So it does not matter what you're doing in your override that the super will try to save the form directly. You can solve your problem by doing:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    credit_request = form.save(commit=False)
    credit_request.credit = credit
    credit_request.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Why don't you just include the `credit_slug` in the url?